# method removeElement() own implementation of Vector class

Tags: c++, vector

I have to implement method for removing specified element in vector. Does anybody knows algoritm for this method?

I need it because of brew platform doesn't support STL.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Shift everything down by one position and decrement the size?

Comment: I have a feeling that if you do not understand how `remove` works then you should not be implementing `vector`.

Comment: STLport works perfectly on BREW. I know for sure because I used to work with it

Comment: I have research and every source told me that it isn't support STL..

Comment: Yes it does. Just try it

Comment: @MariuszChw - note that aleguna wrote "STLport" - http://stlport.sourceforge.net/FAQ.shtml#what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is fairly simple:

```
for each element in vector
    if element = elemToRemove
        delete it
```

And then, it use the deletion by index. Your array is decomposed as:

```
n+1 is the size of the array
i is the cell to delete

[0][1][2]...[i-1][i][i+1]...[n]
-----------------   -----------
part1               part 2
```

You have to shift every elements from `[i+1]` to `[n]` toward the beginning of the array (= shifting `part 2` towards the beginning of the array) in order to make the array still contiguous.

Comment: The actual code will be more complicated due to shifting iterators and size parameter.

Comment: Agree, but he wanted a generic algorithm; he doesn't said what functions he can use...

Comment: In addition to what Pubby said, implementing it like this would be O(n^2) since deleting an element takes linear time.

Comment: Disagree : deleting by index is O(1).

Comment: You said yourself "You have to shift every elements from [i+1] to [n] toward the beginning of the array". Obviously that takes O(n).

Comment: >< I should not be mixing TPs at school and SO... I'm wrong, its O(n). Sorry for the previous dumb comment.